# Test REST API with token identification and json result format

Tags: json, web-services, rest, authentication, token

I want to write a `REST client` that sends a `username and a password`, receives a `token` and uses the `REST API` with it to get data in `json format`. Now I am looking in the internet for hours (e.g. went thru [this side](http://www.programmableweb.com/category/all/apis?data_format=21190)) to find a test API that satisfys the requirements mentioned above but I cannot find anything. Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: Since this can be very helpful for testing apps for other developers and there is no other stackexchange forum I can address this question to, I decided to ask it here.

Comment: Which web-server are you using?

Comment: I develop a client in .net. So if I do get it right I do not need to care what webserver the service is hosted. Am I right?

Comment: you don't need a TEST REST API. Select language of you choice (ruby, python, java), make http calls to your app, and assert on results (use rspec, junit etc.)

Comment: maybe i do noot get it. but i do not have an app i can make calls to (that is why i need a test api) I just  want to develop the client that consumes the rest api. please correct me if i am wrong.